# Javascript - verify onSumbit dynamic inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, verify

I have a form that gets dynamic `<input type="text" />` depends of value -from database- , like this:

```
<form id="data" name="data" method="post" action="..." onSumbit="return VerifyFields()">

<?php
   for ($x=0; $x<count($List); $x++) {
?>

<tr>
   <td> <?php echo $description; ?>  </td>
   <td> <input type="text" name="txt_glo_<?php echo $x; ?>" id=""txt_glo_<?php echo $x; ?> />  </td>
</tr>

<?php
   }
?>

</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript>

   function VerifyFields(){

      var glo = $("#txt_glo_%").val();
      if (glo == ""){
        alert("EMPTY");
        return false;
      } else {
         return true
      }

   }

</script>
```

I need to verify if, for exm., `txt_file_<?php echo $x; ?> == " "` in javascript before i submit the form but i don't know how to do?

Thank you for answers. Greetings

Comment: You'll need to clarify your question.

Comment: Are you using a framework like jQuery?

Comment: What is this: `id=""txt_file_`?

Comment: I edited the question, i really don't know how to explain it... sorry for bad english ;/

Comment: I doubt anyone would use the `$(...)` syntax without using it for jquery

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jQuery solution (it *looks* like you're already using jQuery):

```
var glos = $("input[id^=txt_glo_]");
for(var i=0;i<glos.length;i++){
    var val=$(glos[i]).val();
    if(val==""){
        alert("EMPTY");
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

This will loop through every input with an id that starts with `txt_glo_` and check it's value.

See [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for more about attribute selectors.

Here's a working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/3EZKE/6/).

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to achieve this. The one I'd prefer is giving all the fields the same class, e.g. `validateNotEmpty`.

```
<input class="validateNotEmpty" type="file" ...
<input class="validateNotEmpty" type="text" ...
```

You can even use this for all fields that were set outside the loop. Now you need to check `.each` element when submitted (assuming you are using jQuery).

```
$('form#data').submit(function(){
    var allValid = true;
    $('input.validateNotEmpty').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "" && allValid) {
            alert("please fill in all required fields");
            allValid = false;
            return; // break .each()
        }
    });
    //other validation
    return allValid;
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmJ6F/1/)